# How to iterate through a linked list without buffer overflow?

Tags: c, gcc, data-structures, linked-list, computer-science

I wrote

```
while (ptr->next != NULL) {
        //code here
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
```

and AddressSanitizer is throwing an heap-buffer overflow error.

I added

```
if (ptr->next != NULL) {
    while (ptr->next != NULL) {
        //code here
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

hoping that maybe it would avoid reading a unallocated address, but now AddressSanitizer is terminating my program with SEGV. I'm not really sure how to fix this as I'm new to programming in C, any insights would be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Add enough code for us to recreate the heap-buffer overflow.

Comment: Did you check if ptr is not null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
while(ptr != NULL) {
  // code
  ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

or even

```
for(type* i = ptr; i != NULL; i = i->next) {
  // code
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that result in an error once we reach the last node? The last element wouldn't have a ptr->next

Comment: Last element still has ptr->next, it just points to null. So if ptr is equal to null, you have reached the end.

Comment: You're right, I didn't set the last element to null. That's where my issue was. Thank you